# segmentation fault after fgets - c program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I'm writing a c program as part of my operating system course task.
I found that I have a bug, after "stripping" my code I found the source of the problem is with the fgets function. The "numbers.txt" file has 3 lines of number pairs, I need to read each pair and do something.
I also need to make sure there is only 1 pair of numbers in each line (not allowed 3 numbers in a line)
so my code works for the first 2 lines, but gets "Segmentation Fault(Core Dump) on the third line.

I thought it was because the file only had 3 lines so I tried adding more lines but still only the first 2 worked.
Here is the code:

```
void newlineRemover(char *array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(array); i++)
        if (array[i] == '\n')
            array[i] = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *line = (char*) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    char *token;
    int numbers[2], number, counter = 1;

    puts("please enter the numbers file name:");
    fgets(line, MAXCHAR, stdin); // read from stdin
    newlineRemover(line);

    FILE *fp = fopen(line, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen(): ");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (fgets(line, 50, fp) != NULL) {
        token = strtok(line, " ");
        while (token != NULL) {
            number = atoi(token);
            if (counter != 3 && (number != 0 || strcmp(token, "0") == 0)) {
                numbers[counter - 1] = number;
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "‫‪illegal‬‬ ‫‪input‬‬ ‫‪at‬‬ ‫‪line %d",
                        line_count);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            counter++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        counter = 0;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The code runs until the end of the second while loop run, then when it checks again the `fgets != NULL`, I get the error.

Comment: `counter = 0; numbers[counter - 1]`. Run in a debugger and check the `counter` value when used as index.

Comment: oh my gosh... i was in from my laptop for the past 4 hours trying to solve this! but wait, how come the first AND second runs on the while were good? and only third got error? i mean after first run in the while counter was set to 0 so...

Comment: That's why I suggest you learn to use a debugger. I think it can help you find the problem in a few minutes - it will stop at the seg fault at which point you can easily see which line of code triggers that and look at all the variables.

Comment: Accessing invalid memory is undefined behaviour. It may crash or it may appear to "work" or it can be any other behaviour. And also, on the first line it is fine because you have `counter = 1` for the first time.

Comment: i see. so im coding in eclipse c/c++(yikes) and when i try debugging the error occur on the fgets line.. this is why i though it had to do with the fgets. why was it not showing on the numbers[counter-1] line then? any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately that sometime happens with undefined behaviour. Because the memory gets corrupted the symptom may manifest at a different place. For such issues tools like `valgrind` can help.

Comment: ohh i see. so i only used normal debugger untill now and that got me the wrong idea (that the problem is with fgets) but i know valgrind is a tool that can help you with segmentation fault and memory error.. i never used it before but i will take a look at it. anyway i changed the counter =0 to 1, and now evreything works. thank you sir!

Comment: Just a small coding tip: The standard way to access arrays is to start the index variable from `0` rather than `1` and then just use `numbers[counter]`. What you have is fine but is less maintanable by others because most people would expect a `0` based counter.

Comment: i understand. to be honest this is my first "skech" and i still need to refactor some of this stuff. i like to get the "task complete" and then i revisit the code and refactor evreything (which now that it works i can do)

Comment: the function: `newlineremover()` can be replaced with the statement: `line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: suggest replacing: `while (fgets(line, 50, fp) != NULL) {` with `while ( fgets( line, sizeof( line ), fp ) ) {`

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *line = (char*) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting the value just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing the cast.  2)  the expression: `sizeof( char )` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) 3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror()` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `fgets(line, MAXCHAR, stdin);`  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  (the user can easily make this function fail)

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "‫‪illegal‬‬ ‫‪input‬‬ ‫‪at‬‬ ‫‪line %d", line_count);`  The format string needs to end with `\n` so the data is immediately output to `stderr`

Comment: thank you so much for that my friend. this is not my original full code since i only tried to get the error, i changed a lot of it for this post. but all you'r comments were very usefull (some i knew and some not) and i really appreciate the time you took to write all of those. thank you sir!